# Why would MongoDB resident memory suddenly drop?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

We run Mongo 3.2.8 on Windows 2008. Since the start of this week the server MongoDB runs on has effectively run out of memory every morning. The server has 16gb of RAM. When we see this behaviour mongod.exe reports 6gb of memory, but when we kill the process it frees up around 12gb of memory.

When we leave mongostat running against the server we see vsize sits at 6.3gb consistently, but res drops from 6.0G to 52.0M over a period of about 10 minutes, during which time memory consumption on the boxes goes up until it hits ~100%.

What could cause that to happen? We're using WiredTiger, and we do have some other application processes running on the same server

Comment: "Mongodb uses all free memory, eventually". Normally you don't run other applications or services at same node where you have mongod, because mongod will use all free memory at the situation where total database size with indexes is bigger than machines total memory.